# On a bottom bracket, what does the numeric expression e.g. 1.37x24 mean?

Tags: bottom-bracket

On a bottom bracket I can read 1.37x24 - what do 1.37 and 24 stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It describes the thread of the bottom bracket.

**1.37** stands for the thread diameter and is measured in inches. **24** stands for the pitch size (the distance of the thread in one turn). It's measured in [TPI, threads per inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_thread#Lead.2C_pitch.2C_and_starts).

If the values differ, a bottom bracket won't fit to the frame.